# Getting Permission error with searchfiles

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am getting "You do not have permission to call searchFiles (line 2)." in the code below. When I test run in the editor there is no error. But when I use it in the sheet I get the error. How do I get the permission?

```
function deleteDocByName(fileName){
    var docs=DriveApp.searchFiles('title contains fileName')
    for(n=0;n<docs.length;++n){
        if(docs[n].getName() == fileName){
            var ID = docs[n].getId()
            DriveApp.getFileById(ID).setTrashed(true)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Sandy,

I finally got the function to work. The line that deletes the file in the script you listed was commented. When I removed the comment I was getting undefined ID error. So I assigned value to ID by adding the line below:

```
ID = Logger.log(thisDoc.getId());
```

But that generated ID is not valid error. So I modified the script and got it to work.

Here is what I came up with:

```
function deleteDocByName(fileName){
    var docs = DriveApp.searchFiles('title contains "' + fileName + '"');
    var thisDoc;

    while (docs.hasNext()) {
        thisDoc = docs.next();
        var ID = thisDoc.getId();
        DriveApp.getFileById(ID).setTrashed(true)
    }
 }
```

I also got saveAsTabDelimitedTextFile() to trigger with onChange.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
var docs=DriveApp.searchFiles('title contains fileName')
```

To:

```
var docs=DriveApp.searchFiles('title contains "' + fileName + '"');
```

And you can't use a `for` loop.

Full Code:

```
function deleteDocByName(fileName){
    //fileName = 'Test';
    var docs = DriveApp.searchFiles('title contains "' + fileName + '"');
    var thisDoc;

    Logger.log(docs.hasNext())

    while (docs.hasNext()) {
      thisDoc = docs.next();
      Logger.log(thisDoc.getId());
      //DriveApp.getFileById(ID).setTrashed(true)
    };
}
```

This issue had nothing to do with permissions.  The error is erroneous.

Comment: I tried the changes you suggested but the file is still not getting erased. The filename is getting passed from saveAsTabDelimitedTextFile(). I am getting Permission error when I use the function in sheet. I don't get the error when I ran it in the Script Editor. Not sure how to trigger a function in sheet. Tried onChange in the Sript Editor resource trigger but it does not trigger. What am I doing wrong? I am a newbie.